# Reloading entities from database to existing context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I've got a question about refreshing Entity context.

I have this method that I got out of a [msdn walkthrough](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WPF-Entity-Framework-MVVM-78cdc204). It has a long running context.

```
protected async override void GetData()
{
    ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    ObservableCollection<ProductVM> _products = new ObservableCollection<ProductVM>();
    var products = await (from p in db.Products
                           orderby p.ProductShortName
                           select p).ToListAsync();
    foreach (Product prod in products)
    {
        _products.Add(new ProductVM { IsNew = false, TheEntity = prod });
    }
    Products = _products;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
    ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

It doesn't really function the way I thought it would. Let's say I run the application, without changing data application-side, I open the SQL Server database and change a value on an existing record and add a new record.

```
private void RefreshData()
{
    GetData();
}
```

When I run RefreshData() I thought it would refresh the data completely, however only the new record comes through, the value on the existing record on the application-side does not get updated.

I have seen the only way to be sure that the context gets completely refreshed is to create a new context instance.

However, I'd like to understand why/what is happening. Why is the value not updated?

Comment: I'm hoping this would help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592904(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbContext` in Entity Framework automatically caches data that it retrieves from the database. You may explicitly reload the entities by calling the `Reload()` method of each one of them:

```
foreach (Product prod in products)
{
    db.Entry(prod).Reload();
    _products.Add(new ProductVM { IsNew = false, TheEntity = prod });
}
```

...or you could disable the tracking:

```
var products = await (from p in db.Products
                       orderby p.ProductShortName
                       select p).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

More options and information are available here: http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/.